# Method references not complying to functional interfaces, yet compilation does not fail... Is it by design?

Tags: java, java-8

In the snippet below, both usages of `forEach()` compile:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BigDecimal spent = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    Stream.of(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.TEN).forEach(spent::add);

    Set<BigDecimal> set = new HashSet<>();
    Stream.of(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.TEN).forEach(set::add);
}
```

I am aware of the inanity of the first example (`BigDecimal` is immutable); the problem is not here:

- `Stream`'s `forEach()` takes a [`Consumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) as an argument, and the signature of the SAM (note: Single Abstract Method) says that it returns `void`;
- yet, `BigDecimal`'s `.add()` returns a `BigDecimal`, and `Set`'s `.add()` (`Collection`'s, in fact) returns a `boolean`;
- therefore the signature of both methods above don't match a `Consumer`;
- yet both examples compile.

But *this* does not compile:

```
// whatever is returned; BigDecimal.ZERO, null... -> compile error
Stream.of(BigDecimal.ONE).forEach(b -> { return false; });
```

Is it by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Remember that a return type is not part of a method signature.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) For your first case, we go to the [runtime evaluation of the lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4).

> The method's body has the effect of evaluating the lambda body, if it
>   is an expression, or of executing the lambda body, if it is a block;
>   **if a result is expected, it is returned from the method**.

As for the second case

> If the function type's result is `void`, the lambda body is either a
>   statement expression or a void-compatible block.

which yours isn't, ie. `Consumer#accept(Object)`'s function type is `void`, but your lambda body is neither a statement expression nor [a void-compatible block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2). It is a value-compatible block.

> Is it by design?

I say yes. In the second case, you are explicitly stating that you are returning a value. But this isn't allowed by the target functional interface method.

In your first snippet

```
Stream.of(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.TEN).forEach(spent::add);
```

you simply have more flexibility. The expression can have side effects and you may want to ignore the returned value.

Comment: "a return type is not part of a method signature" <-- uh, sorry but `CallSite` disagrees, and so does `MethodType` for instance; while I may understand the "result is expected" part, I don't agree with the aforementioned statement...

Comment: @fge Are you referring to the `java.lang.invoke` types? What do those say?

Comment: What do you mean, "what do they say"? Using this API, you won't be able to lookup `BigDecimal`'s `.add()` if you expect it to return `void`; do I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: @fge I don't know that API, so I was asking in what sense they disagree.

Comment: @fge: You're mixing apples and oranges.  The JLS does not consider return types to be part of the signature; the JVMS does.  Everything in java.lang.invoke uses JVMS rules.  (Before you shout "inconsistent", bear in mind that the language and VM have different type systems, and quite reasonably so as they have different purposes and audiences.)  Sotiros is entirely correct here.

Comment: @BrianGoetz although I have accepted this answer, it is your comment that is the answer, really; I need to learn more. Now, for some bugging: JCIP v2, please, pretty please!